# Creating specific matrix in pure Python

Tags: python

I have little problem here. As I am not good in math I can't figure this out tho.

I need to create function that takes `n` as a parameter which is matrix size and creates matrix of this type

```
 [[1, -8, 9, -16]
 [2, -7, 10, -15]
 [3, -6, 11, -14]
 [4, -5, 12, -13]]
```

All I achieved was this

```py
def arrange_matrix2(n):
    matrix = []
    row = []
    num = 1
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            row.append(num)
            num += 1
        matrix.append(row)
        row = []

    final_matrix = map(list, zip(*matrix))
    print(*final_matrix)
```

It creates matrix that looks like this

```
[1, 4, 7]
[2, 5, 8]
[3, 6, 9]
```

Also. Is there a way to create matrix that is arranged by column without using `zip()` function?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: actually you are moving from top->bottom->top-->bottom this is the pattern

Comment: I know theory. I have no idea how to implement it

Comment: This is a snake pattern. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-matrix-in-snake-pattern-from-the-last-column/

Comment: If you will search by snake pattern you will get lot of resources :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything fancy here. First, preallocate your output:

```
final_matrix = [[0] * n for _ in range(n)]
```

Now you can do whatever you want with the indices. For example, here is a very simple approach:

```
num = 1
for j in range(n):
    for i in range(n):
        if j % 2:
            final_matrix[-(i + 1)][j] = -num
        else:
            final_matrix[i][j] = num
        num += 1
```

The modulo operator returns the remainder, and can therefore be used to check for divisibility. `j % 2` will be 1 if `j` is odd, 0 if even. So odd columns get reversed and negated. The row index `-(i + 1)` is a Python shorthand for `n - (i + 1)`. As the actual `i` goes 0->`n-1`, the index of odd columns goes `n-1`->0.

Comment: that is what I needed. Thank you a lot. And for explanation too :)

Comment: Start small. If you understand the simple things, you understand everything. If you only know complicated things, you're just fooling yourself.